# What is allowed to do in destructors in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm trying to understand what is allowed to do in destructors.

The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1) says: "For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes execution results in undefined behavior".
[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) describes destruction sequence this way: "For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after the body of the destructor is executed, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class".

Does this mean, that in the following code calling method from its member's destructor is UB? Or by "referring" standard means something particular?

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(Callback cb) : cb_(cb) {}

  ~Foo() {
    // body of Bar destructor finished at this moment;
    // cb_() calls Bar::call_me()
    cb_();
  }

  Callback cb_;
};

struct Bar {
  // pass callback with captured this
  Bar() : foo_([this]() { call_me(); }) {
  }

  void call_me() {
  }

  // foo is a member, its destructor will be called after Bar destructor
  Foo foo_;
};
```

Also, what does the phrase "after the destructor finishes" from the standard mean exactly? After the body of a destructor finishes? Or after all members and base classes destroyed?
I think the answer to the last question is the key to understanding what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: compiling and running this example can be misleading, because I'd expect it to work just "fine". If `call_me` would access a member of `Bar` which itself has a non-trivial destructor, the issue might be more obvious.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Even then I don't see a problem. The cited paragraph clearly says "after the destructor finishes", not "after the body of the destructor finishes". As long as `call_me` accesses only members of Bar that are not yet destroyed (i.e., defined before `foo_`, all is fine.

Comment: First paragraph only means that after `foo` is destroyed you cannot access its members or call its methods. Second one means that in addition to the actions in user-defined destructor, members destructors are always automatically invoked after user destructor finishes. So, "after the destructor finishes" means "after the body of the destructor finishes" + all automatic destructors have finished.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I wanted to keep example as simple as possible. With main function, includes and using statements this example compiles and executes just fine.

Comment: The core case is `my_class *ptr = new my_class; delete ptr; ptr->member_function();`. The call to`member_function()` is made after the destructor has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destructor of `Bar` has not finished, and therefore referring to a member of `Bar`, and indeed calling a member function of `Bar` within its destructor is OK.

Calling member functions of the super object can be a bit precarious though, since member functions may access sub objects, and some sub objects may have already been destroyed by the time the member function is called, and in that case accessing the destroyed objects would result in undefined behaviour. This is not the case in your example.

> Or by "referring" standard means something particular?

I think it means to form a pointer or a reference to a sub object. As is done in the example below the rule.

---

> Also, what does the phrase "after the destructor finishes" from the standard mean exactly? After the body of a destructor finishes? Or after all members and base classes destroyed?

The latter.

The body is executed first, then the destructor calls the sub object destructors, and then the destructor has finished.

Comment: My interpretation is different. Which part of the standard supports this answer?

Comment: @chill See the section `[class.dtor]` in particular `a destructor for class X calls the destructors for X's direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for X's non-virtual direct base classes and, if X is the most derived class ([class.base.init]), its destructor calls the destructors for X's virtual base classes`. I don't think the standard actually  defines what "finish execution" means, so we are left with human interpretation. If the destructor is calling sub object destructors, then my interpretation is that it hasn't finished executing.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I just found the same,  "After executing the body of the destructor [...] a destructor for class X calls ..." i.e. it is still executing, since it calls things.